# Counting the number of occurrences of every distinct value of a list

Tags: c#

Ok so I'm basically creating some algorithms for factoring numbers , and storing said factors in a list.

So for a number like 24 , the list of factors would look like this:

> l = { 2 , 2 ,2 , 3 }

Due to the fact that I'm working with very big numbers , I need a way to efficiently find how many times each different value occurs in the list. 
In this basic example 2 occurs 3 times , and 3 occurs 1 time.

Is there a C# List<> function that can do that for me ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
var counts = list.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

It will produce dictionary with number and count

Comment: Love you, thanks ^^.
I'll mark your reply as the Answer as soon as I can - 6mins.

Comment: However, this creates a new dictionary always. So if you use that code on every new number it will be horribly inefficient. @CataVisan: edited my answer to show a different approach using a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GroupBy` and a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, int> numGroups = l
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Now you can use this dictionary for lookups:

```
int number = 2;
int count = 0;
numGroups.TryGetValue(number, out count);
Console.Write("List contains {0} {1} times.", number, count);
```

However, this needs to create a new dictionary on every new number, i assume that this is not efficient enough. So you should reuse the same dictionary and add/increase the number, for example in this way:

```
Dictionary<int, int> NumberLookup = new Dictionary<int, int>();

public void CalculcateNextFactor()
{        
    int nextNumber = // calculate the next number...
    if (NumberLookup.ContainsKey(nextNumber))
        NumberLookup[nextNumber]++;
    else
        NumberLookup.Add(nextNumber, 1);
}
```

If you want the count for a given number you can use `TryGetValue` as in the first approach:

```
int count = 0;
NumberLookup.TryGetValue(number, out count);
```